# asp.net Grid (using knockout + bootstrap, crud, filtering,sorting)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, grid, components

For the project I need to find out some existing controls for asp.net Grid within the project. Grid should do all CRUD, sorting, filtering.

We use latest technologies: mvc, knockout, bootstrap, webapi (called from knockout).

Of course, there are links to tutorials of "how to create your grid ...", but I was expected to find some existing Components as it seems that such kind of grid should be used within different projects.

The problem is that I have not found any existing well supported grid components. Are not there any?

**Update:**
I have found Telerik Kendo UI that can support all necessary features.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen Telerik MVC components?

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/razor/grid

Comment: this is the only component i have found yesterday and I've got the answer from telerik also... is there any alternative?